Arguments for a tikz legend in combination with datavisualization library
I have created a tikz plot with the library datavisualization and added a legend. How can I add further arguments to the legend (like font size, fill color, etc.)? There is much documentation for legend settings which usually works but does not seem compatible with use of datavisualization.
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \datavisualization [
        school book axes,
        visualize as smooth line/.list={func1,func2},
        func1={style={blue,dashed}, label in legend={text={$h=0.2$}}},
        func2={style={blue,solid}, label in legend={text={$h=0.1$}}},
        legend=north west inside, % here I would like to add arguments
        ]
        data [set=func1] {
            x, y
            0, 1
            0.2, 1.4
            0.4, 1.96
            0.6, 2.744
            0.8, 3.8416
            1, 5.3782
        }
        data [set=func2] {
            x, y
            0, 1
            0.1, 1.2
            0.2, 1.44
            0.3, 1.728
            0.4, 2.0736
            0.5, 2.4883
            0.6, 2.986
            0.7, 3.5832
            0.8, 4.2998
            0.9, 5.1598
            1, 6.1917
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}


General answer: use/define stylesheets, as described extensively in chp. 84 https://tikz.dev/dv-stylesheets . // Examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btikz-datavisualization%5D+legend . // It will be easier to answer your question when you specify your desired outcome more clearly. // datavisualization is similar AND not compatibel with pgfplots, if you meant that.
